# twitter bootstrap glyphicon link in dynamic error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the glyphicons that come with Twitterbootstrap in a Rails application. According to the docs,

```
All icons require an <i> tag with a unique class, prefixed with icon-. To use, place the following code just about anywhere:
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
```

I use the following code to generate error messages, but I don't know how to include the  tag.

```
   <ul>
      <% @errors.each do | msg| %>
      <li><%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash", :class => "icon-remove" %></li>
    <% end %>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to just include the icon tag as an `html_safe` string. For example, if you wanted to use the icon at the start of each `li` element (presumably getting rid of the normal list item markers by adding the `unstyled` class to your `ul` element):

```
<li><%= content_tag :div, "<i class="icon-remove"></i> #{msg}".html_safe, :class => "flash" %></li>
```

(Also, note that setting the `id` like that will possibly result in more than one element with the same `id`, which you shouldn't have.)

Comment: the flash id used to be a class, but once I tried to include 'icon-remove' i changed 'flash' to an 'id', with which I attach style colors. Do you know another way that I can do it since icon-remove is now the class?

Comment: Why not just apply multiple classes (ie. `class="flash icon-remove"`)? Either way, you do not want to set `icon-remove` as the `class` for the `div`. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion, but can't confirm it works because Twitter's looking for the icon in a non-existent 'img' folder, something I did't think would happen if I used the Twitter gem http://localhost:3000/img/glyphicons-halflings.png

Comment: That does sound a little weird. Which bootstrap gem are you using?

Comment: ok, I got the icon to show, but if I do "<i class='flash icon-remove..." for the class with styles in the style sheet like this .flash.icon-remove {background-color: #FCC;
  border: solid 1px #C66;}  , only the icon is getting colored, not the actual flash message

Comment: Sorry, I think something got lost in communication there, `flash` and `icon-remove` should be set on two different elements. You'll want to add `class="flash"` to your containing `div`, and add the `<i class="icon-remove"></i>` inside that div. I've slightly updated my original answer, but I think that line should do what you're after. The main thing to remember is that you never want to be adding the `icon-*` classes to another element, always use them by themselves on an empty `i` element where you want the icon to appear in the document.

Comment: actually Twitter has built in functionality to clear alerts data-dismiss="alert" but I couldn't get it to work this way :data => {:dismiss => 'alert'}. do you know how?

Comment: I couldn't say off the top of my head -- that's probably better as a new question.